# Neural Network bias simple workings

Tags: neural-network

I've created a neural network in Matlab and now I'm planning to take the weights and implement the network in C++. The network works but now that I'm trying to implement it in C++ I feel that I don't actually understand it.

To take a really simple example: one input -> three nodes in hidden layer(tansig) -> one output node (purelin).

Input Weights for layer one are :   9.3842 ,
                                    7.1205 ,
                                  -14.6497

with a bias of : -7.8820, 
                 -3.4257, 
                -14.2522,

Weights for output node are : 0.5760 ,  -0.9019,   -0.4809,

with a bias of : -0.1413

I've been trying with inputs :0 and 0.498  with targets 5.0145 and 5.3314

The problem is that I can't get ( or close to) those targets by performing the calculations manually. To give you an idea of what I'm doing, take 0 as input;

0*w1 + b = -7.8820,

0*w2 + b2 = -3.4257 ,

0*w3 + b3 = -14.2522 ,

Applying the activation function tansig :

output1 = tansig(-7.8820) = -1

output2 = tansig(-3.4257) = -.997

output3 = tansig(-14.2522) = -1

For the final node,

output1*weight1 = -.5760

output2*weight2 = .900

output3*weight3 = .4809

sum + b = .9462

That's how I thought it worked but obviously not. I think maybe I don't understand what's happening with the tansig activation function.

Thanks for reading and any help,

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, you need to show your code. If not, you might want to move this to CrossValidated.

Comment: I think that some weight are missing, in the hidden layer it should be more then 3 weight (it should be 3 for every node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, silly me, the problem was that I forgot about scaling. The NN (in Matlab) automatically scales input between [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

Your `tansig()` activation function ranges from -1 to 1, so it is probably a `tanh()`. It looks like a `sigmoid()*2-1` or an `arctan()*2/PI` but the curve vary a little differently. You might want to see what the tanh() looks like: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dtanh%28x%29

Your pseudocode looks fine, but I did not try to put back in the numbers. Maybe the only thing you forgot to write is:

```
sum = output1*weight1 + output2*weight2 + output3*weight3
final_output = sum + b
```

Do not forget that the weights are initialized at random in such a neural network and that they need to be learned with the backpropagation algorithm (through many gradient descents on each weight in a big loop) or another similar learning technique.